# quicksort alghoritm in R

Tags: r

i have a problem with this code (sort a vector of number from smaller to largest).

```
qs<- function(x){ 
if (length(x)<= 1) return (x) 
pivot<- x[1] 
rest<- x[-1] 
sv1<- rest[rest<pivot] 
sv2<- rest[rest>=pivot] 
sv1<-qs(sv1) 
sv2<- qs(sv2) 
return(c(sv1,pivot,sv2))
```

the doubt is essentially on how the variables are modified when function are recalled. 
For example, how the code work with a simply vector like this:

```
x<-c(5,2,8,3)
```

Thanks

Comment: Because R is working by-value instead of by-reference, every instance of `sv1` (et al) are completely separate from the same-named variables in nested/recursive calls to `qs`. What specific problem are you seeing? Do you have a vector where it is not behaving as expected?

Comment: i have problem with the value of the variable if i try manually. For example with the vector `c(5,3,8,2)`. Initially `sv1=c(3,2)` and `sv2=8`. In the first call to `qs(sv1)` the values will be `sv1=2` and sv2 empty. The nested second call `qs(sv1)` returns `sv1=2`. Then there is the call `qs(sv2)` where sv2 is 8. In this way the problem is that in sv1 there isn't the 3 anymore for sort the vector.

Comment: *"if I try manually"* ... is that within `browser()` or are you just overwriting variables as you play on the R console? The call `qs( c(5,2,8,3) )` works for me.

Comment: the code in R works with all vectors. I mean if I try to reproduce how the function works with paper and pen on that vector, as i did above.

Comment: This sounds like you're asking how a recursive functions works. StackOverflow isn't really the best site for tutorial questions like that.

Comment: with other recursive functions everything is ok, maybe the doubts comes from the two consecutive calls. The call scheme should be this: initially: `sv1=c(3,2)` `sv2=8`. First call `qs(sv1)`: `sv1=2` and `sv2 empty`, nested second call to `qs(sv1)` returns `sv1=2` and first call `qs(sv2)` return 0 (empty), so the final value that first call `qs(sv1)` returns is `c(2,3)` because the pivot in the first call is 3. Then first call to `qs(sv2)` where sv2 have the initial value of 8, returns 8. So, in conclusion `sv1=c(2,3)`, `pivot=5`, `sv2=8`. Vector sorted. Right?